# How to Distinct query result over 2 of 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a query like this:

```
WITH CTE_KELOMPOKINFORMASI (KelompokInformasi, XBRLItem_ItemId) 
AS (
SELECT a.Id AS KelompokInformasi, c.XBRLItem_ItemId
FROM XBRLNamespaces a INNER JOIN XBRLHypercubes b 
ON a.XBRLView_ViewId = b.XBRLView_ViewId 
INNER JOIN XBRLHypercubeDimensionItems c 
ON b.XBRLHypercubeId = c.XBRLHypercube_XBRLHypercubeId 
WHERE a.Id like '%KBIK_AAKL%')

SELECT f.KelompokInformasi, e.Name AS DimensionName, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.Name ORDER BY e.Name DESC) AS 'Number'
FROM XBRLDefinitionRoleDomainItems a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLDefinitionRoleDimensionItems b
ON a.XBRLDefinitionRole_DefinitionRoleId = b.XBRLDefinitionRole_DefinitionRoleId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLItems c ON a.XBRLItem_ItemId = c.ItemId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLLabels d ON a.XBRLItem_ItemId = d.XBRLItem_ItemId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLItems e ON b.XBRLItem_ItemId=e.ItemId
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_KELOMPOKINFORMASI f ON b.XBRLItem_ItemId=f.XBRLItem_ItemId
WHERE b.XBRLItem_ItemId=f.XBRLItem_ItemId
```

and it gives result like this:

```
Kelompok Informasi     DimensionName       Number
KBIK_AAKL              JWAAKT              1
KBIK_AAKL              JWAAKT              2
KBIK_AAKL              JWAAKT              3
KBIK_AAKL              SNOUPL              1
KBIK_AAKL              SNOUPL              2
KBIK_AAKL              KOKOLT              1
KBIK_AAKL              KOKOLT              2
KBIK_AAKL              KOKOLT              3
KBIK_AAKL              KOKOLT              4
```

Is it possible if i **DISTINCT** my result again by "DimensionName", so i have a result just like this:

```
KelompokInformasi      DimensionName       Number
KBIK_AAKL              JWAAKT              1
KBIK_AAKL              SNOUPL              2
KBIK_AAKL              KOKOLT              3
```

i tried to do distinct like code below but it doesn't work

```
SELECT DISTINCT DimensionName
FROM (SELECT f.KelompokInformasi, e.Name AS DimensionName, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.Name ORDER BY e.Name DESC) AS 'Number'
FROM XBRLDefinitionRoleDomainItems a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLDefinitionRoleDimensionItems b
ON a.XBRLDefinitionRole_DefinitionRoleId = b.XBRLDefinitionRole_DefinitionRoleId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLItems c ON a.XBRLItem_ItemId = c.ItemId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLLabels d ON a.XBRLItem_ItemId = d.XBRLItem_ItemId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLItems e ON b.XBRLItem_ItemId=e.ItemId
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_KELOMPOKINFORMASI f ON b.XBRLItem_ItemId=f.XBRLItem_ItemId
WHERE b.XBRLItem_ItemId=f.XBRLItem_ItemId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your distinct on the inner subquery and row number them on the outer Select

```
WITH CTE_KELOMPOKINFORMASI (KelompokInformasi, XBRLItem_ItemId) 
AS (
SELECT a.Id AS KelompokInformasi, c.XBRLItem_ItemId
FROM XBRLNamespaces a INNER JOIN XBRLHypercubes b 
ON a.XBRLView_ViewId = b.XBRLView_ViewId 
INNER JOIN XBRLHypercubeDimensionItems c 
ON b.XBRLHypercubeId = c.XBRLHypercube_XBRLHypercubeId 
WHERE a.Id like '%KBIK_AAKL%')

Select A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.DimensionName DESC) AS 'Number'
FROM (
    SELECT distinct f.KelompokInformasi, e.Name AS DimensionName
    FROM XBRLDefinitionRoleDomainItems a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLDefinitionRoleDimensionItems b
    ON a.XBRLDefinitionRole_DefinitionRoleId = b.XBRLDefinitionRole_DefinitionRoleId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLItems c ON a.XBRLItem_ItemId = c.ItemId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLLabels d ON a.XBRLItem_ItemId = d.XBRLItem_ItemId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLItems e ON b.XBRLItem_ItemId=e.ItemId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_KELOMPOKINFORMASI f ON b.XBRLItem_ItemId=f.XBRLItem_ItemId
    WHERE b.XBRLItem_ItemId=f.XBRLItem_ItemId
) AS A
```

Comment: Distinct succeed but in column number give result 1,1,1. Why this could happen? i want the result in colum Number is 1,2,3

Comment: @bagusofterror stripped out the PARTITION BY, that was the cause

Comment: Why all the downvotes? If there is faulty logic here, help me fix it.

Comment: Woww good answer Wruckie .. Without PARTITION BY it works .. Thanks very much @wruckie

Comment: I don't know who gives the downvotes .. so what can i do to fix it without minus? i marked it and upvoted it

Answer (score 0):

Just Filter with Your Row_Number

Try like this

```
SELCT KelompokInformasi,DimensionName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS 'NUMBER' FROM
(
SELECT f.KelompokInformasi, e.Name AS DimensionName, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.Name ORDER BY e.Name DESC) AS 'RN'    
FROM XBRLDefinitionRoleDomainItems a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLDefinitionRoleDimensionItems b
ON a.XBRLDefinitionRole_DefinitionRoleId = b.XBRLDefinitionRole_DefinitionRoleId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLItems c ON a.XBRLItem_ItemId = c.ItemId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLLabels d ON a.XBRLItem_ItemId = d.XBRLItem_ItemId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLItems e ON b.XBRLItem_ItemId=e.ItemId
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_KELOMPOKINFORMASI f ON b.XBRLItem_ItemId=f.XBRLItem_ItemId
WHERE b.XBRLItem_ItemId=f.XBRLItem_ItemId

) AS T

WHERE RN = 1
```

**(OR)**

```
SELCT KelompokInformasi,DimensionName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS 'NUMBER' FROM
    (
    SELECT f.KelompokInformasi, e.Name AS DimensionName,          
    FROM XBRLDefinitionRoleDomainItems a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLDefinitionRoleDimensionItems b
    ON a.XBRLDefinitionRole_DefinitionRoleId = b.XBRLDefinitionRole_DefinitionRoleId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLItems c ON a.XBRLItem_ItemId = c.ItemId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLLabels d ON a.XBRLItem_ItemId = d.XBRLItem_ItemId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN XBRLItems e ON b.XBRLItem_ItemId=e.ItemId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_KELOMPOKINFORMASI f ON b.XBRLItem_ItemId=f.XBRLItem_ItemId
    WHERE b.XBRLItem_ItemId=f.XBRLItem_ItemId
    GROUP BY f.KelompokInformasi, e.Name        
    ) AS T
```

Comment: This query is works but in column Number i want to result 1,2,3 not 1,1,1. I added "SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.DimensionName ORDER BY T.DimensionName DESC) AS 'Numbers'" but why it gives the same result 1,1,1?

Comment: @bagusofterror because our where condition is to take RowNumber= 1. that's why i added one more Row_Number as SNO

Comment: Marked Vignesh. Almost done, but now the column number gives 1,4,10 from the sequence number. I just want my number is 1,2,3. Maybe i will modify again the query. Thanks Vignesh

Comment: Woww that's amazing brother. It helps, it works. Thank you very much. You are very genius Vignesh.

Comment: @VigneshKumar Why did you even need a row_number in the inner query? A distinct should have reduced it down to three rows. Your query is unnecessarily complicated.